# Pandas - Replace Integers with Floats

Tags: python, pandas

I want to "recode" an integer variable into a float variable in Pandas. But this does not seem to work like I would have expected. Basically I have a 1-6 Scale which I want to assign new values to.

My current approach with an example:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [1,2,3,4,5]  
})

df2['B'] = df2['A'].replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0.85, 0.70, 0.55, 0.40])

print df2
```

Result:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  0
2  3  0
3  4  0
4  5  0
```

What is a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> df2['A'].astype(float).replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0.85, 0.70, 0.55, 0.40])
0    1.00
1    0.85
2    0.70
3    0.55
4    0.40
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

May be more appropriate way to do this is to use [`pandas.Series.map()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map):

```
>>> df2['A'].map(dict(zip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0.85, 0.70, 0.55, 0.40])))
0    1.00
1    0.85
2    0.70
3    0.55
4    0.40
Name: A, dtype: float64
```